# Easy question: Read file, reverse it and write to another file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have:

```
 o = File.new("ouput.txt", "rw+")
 File.new("my_file.txt").lines.reverse_each { |line|
       ?????  line 
 }
 o.close
```

I don't know what method to use to write to the file output `o`

Comment: You shouldn't use meta tag. See this : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`puts` understands arrays, so you can simplify this to:

```
File.open("f2.txt","w") {|o| o.puts File.readlines("f1.txt").reverse}
```

Comment: Didnt even think of this, nice.

Comment: I don't want to write to another file. I only want to print it on console. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was easy, what I don't quite get is why is not documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html)?

```
o = File.new("ouput.txt", "w+")
File.new("my_file.txt").lines.reverse_each { |line|
    o.puts line 
}
o.close
```

Comment: It isn't documented there because `puts` isn't a member of class `File`.  It's actually a member of class `IO`, and class `File` is a subclass of `IO`.  The documentation for it is here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna wanna do something more like...

```
new_text = File.readlines('my_file').reverse.join
File.open('my_file', 'w+') { |file| file.write(new_text) }
```

Check out [this documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html) to figure out what `w+` means.

Answer (score 0):

For large files, avoid using readlines, as it'll be really slow/inefficient.  Consider using a gem like [Elif](http://elif.rubyforge.org/) for this sort of thing.