# How to read a file backwards and then forwards with ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

I have svn log files which are a few kb to 1 mb, usually kb. They contain zero, one or more of the below blocks of text:

```
---------------------------------
r3457 | programmer1 | 03.20.2015
changed file1.txt
added file7.txt
etc...
team1: adding new feature to app
---------------------------------
```

I want to get the last check-in in each file. In the above example, last check in is 3457.

So, for this, I am going to read a file from bottom, keep reading upwards till i find a dashed line. Then, I will move forwards and read the next line which has the last check in.

How do I do this ? I read a bit about `elif` but could not figure out the api. I also tried one so post, but its not clear - [Easy question: Read file, reverse it and write to another file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445212/easy-question-read-file-reverse-it-and-write-to-another-file-in-ruby)

I can do this, but I don't want to write it to another file.

```
o = File.new("ouput.txt", "w+")

File.new("my_file.txt").lines.reverse_each { |line|
    o.puts line 
}
o.close
```

Thanks a million !

Comment: Suppose the record size is at most `n`. You could open the file and [IO#seek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-seek) to position `size(filename) - n` (using [File::size](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-size)) and look for the last record from that point in the file.

Comment: Why not just keep the lines you read as you're reading backwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few kb to 1 mb, no need to do complicated byte level file reading. Just read the lines in an array and get the last dashed line using `rindex`.

```
ar = File.readlines('test.txt')
# dashes_idx = ar.rindex("---------------------------------\n")
dashes_idx = ar.rindex{|line| line.end_with?("----------\n")}
p ar[dashes_idx + 1].split(" | ").first
```

Comment: Why not use `File.readlines('test.txt')` instead of `File.open("test.txt").readlines`? This is also a good candidate for `slice_before`, like `ar.slice_before(/^-+$/).last.split...` but a benchmark should be run to see whether there are benefits one way over the other.

Comment: `File.readlines('test.txt')` surely is an improvement, thanks. I tend to avoid regular expressions for readability and maintainability reasons.

Comment: Avoiding regexp is a good thing; Too many use them as their go-to tool, and then write code that runs slower or introduces extremely subtle bugs. They can also reduce code and improve the speed if used and written correctly. There's just a time and place to use them.

Comment: @steenslag - good answer. the only problem is that this will work when the number of dashes is fixed. suppose it changes, then the code will not work. How do I make the above code work if there are AT LEAST 10 dashes ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made a log-analyzer like this:

```
Bytes = 10000
File.open(filename){|f|
  puts "Open #{f.path}, get last #{Bytes} bytes"
  f.seek(-Bytes, IO::SEEK_END  )
  puts f.readlines
}
```

This snipplet reads the last 10000 Bytes of the file (see the minus before `Bytes`) and prints it.

Just estimate the size of one record and try to read the last x entries. Inside this entries you can go for the last one.

One propose:

```
N      = 1000 #average size of one record
File.open(filename){|f|
  puts "Get approx. get last 5 records"
  f.seek(-(5*N), IO::SEEK_END  )
  tail = f.read
  last_record = tail.split('----------').last
}
```

Comment: I don't want to read approximate records. I just want to read a file backwards, exactly one line at a time. I also want to be able to move forward, one line at time.